# React Ionic - How can a menu access a router parameter?

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework

I start from the SideMenu Ionic App.

I have a main page which takes a "date" props from the route

In the left menu I will put a calendar in which the date provided in the route will be highlighted.

**How can I proceed to access to the date parameter in my menu?**

```
<IonApp>
        <IonReactRouter>
            <IonSplitPane contentId="main">

                <IonMenu contentId="main" date="????">
                </IonMenu>
                <IonPage id="main">
                    <IonContent>
                        <IonRouterOutlet>
                            <Route
                                path="/Organisation/:date?"
                                render={(props) => (
                                    <Organisation {...props} />
                                )}
                                exact={true}
                            />
                        </IonRouterOutlet>
                    </IonContent>
                </IonPage>
            </IonSplitPane>
        </IonReactRouter>
</IonApp>
```

I have tried several solutions but no one works well. Which is the best one?

- putting everything below IonRouterOutlet, i.e. moving the IonMenu inside the Organisation component. I have tried this but the left menu disappears 1 sec at each page change (reloaded?). It is not nice.
- passing a callback function to the Organisation component that will send the date back to the IonApp component. I have tried this but it generates infinite loops
- other ?

Thanks

Comment: If your `<Organisation />` component takes `date` from route, it is a good practice to specify it in the props and not to use `...props`. There's a saying: _"Prefer explicit over implicit"_. Without prior explanation, it wouldn't be apparent from the code.

Answer (score 2):

the best approach it to start with the sidemenu template Ionic provides.

here is how I have structured it in my sample app

```
      <IonApp>
        <>
          {authInfo?.loggedIn === true ? (
            <IonReactRouter>
              <IonSplitPane contentId="main">
                <Menu />
                <IonRouterOutlet id="main">
                  <Route path="/page/:name" component={Page} exact />
                  <Route path="/tabs" component={TabRootPage} />
                  <Redirect from="/" to="/tabs" exact />
                </IonRouterOutlet>
              </IonSplitPane>
            </IonReactRouter>
          ) : (
            <IonReactRouter>
              <Route
                path="/create-account"
                component={CreateAccountPage}
                exact
              />
              <Route path="/login" component={LoginPage} exact />
              <Redirect from="/" to="/login" exact />
            </IonReactRouter>
          )}
        </>
      </IonApp>
```

I am using react context for some state information which is stored in my `AuthProvider`

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <AuthProvider>
    <App />
  </AuthProvider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

You can then get the data out of the context in the `Menu` and you don't need to pass parameters around.

examples: [Video and Blog about Managing State in Ionic React Applications](https://dev.to/aaronksaunders/learn-to-build-mobile-apps-with-ionic-framework-reactjs-video-series-pt2-13e7)

[Context provides a way to pass data through the component tree without having to pass props down manually at every level.](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

Comment: I have tried something in this direction but it generates infinite loops: my Organisation component calls a back-up function given by the App component to transfer the route parameter. The App component updates the context which is transmitted to my calendar which needs to be updated and generate a general update...

Answer (score 0):

[IonReactRouter](https://ionicframework.com/docs/react/navigation) uses [React Router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web) under the hood, so definitely refer to their documentation to learn more.

---

You can access the url parameters anywhere within `<IonReactRouter/>` via `useParams` hook.
- https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Hooks/useparams

Add it right to your `<IonMenu/>` component definition

```
const IonMenu = () => {
  let { date } = useParams(); // here is your date

  return <>...</>
}
```

Use this hook anywhere you need the params. This way, you avoid [prop drilling](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/prop-drilling), ie. the need to pass props to distant places.

Comment: Thanks but here IonMenu being not below IonReactRouter, useParams does not provide the date. I have tried to move IonMenu under the router but the menu disappears for 1sec at each click. I think it is the behavior of IonSplitPane who hides the menu by default before showing it again when he notices the screen is big... What is the best strategy according to you?

Comment: @Zorro07 But in your snippet code it is within `IonReactRouter`. Anyway, if not, you need to put the Provider higher in the hierarchy. It is safe to move the Provider as it doesn't render anything. You don't have to move your `Menu` component.

Comment: It seems useParams works only below <IonRouterOutlet>, not <IonReactRouter>

Comment: this is a solution that can be properly solved using state management.. you can probably jhack something together eventually, but it will be a hack... also you have your routing structured incorrectly for using the sideMenu

Comment: @Zorro07 ~~Okay, I am not familiar with `Ionic` framework. Can you move the Outlet to the top level?~~ /EDIT: After going through the docs https://ionicframework.com/docs/react/navigation#ionrouteroutlet for IonRouterOutlet and IonReactRouter, it should not be the case. IonReactRouter should provide the needed context.

Comment: Indeed the Outlet can't be moved higher. And it seems IonSplitPane is not designed to be inside an router Outlet...

Comment: I gave you a link to a project that properly implements this...not sure what more you can ask for - the code above works, show where the Outlets should be placed